# Access home drive on Windows partition - Cannot find it!

Tags: partitioning, windows

From root, where can I access the `C:` drive on my Windows partition?

Comment: If Widnows 8 or 10 make sure fast start up is off. http://askubuntu.com/questions/145902/unable-to-mount-windows-ntfs-filesystem-due-to-hibernation and: http://askubuntu.com/questions/145902/unable-to-mount-windows-ntfs-filesystem-due-to-hibernation

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Technically it will be available under `/media/Your-User-Name/UUID-Of-Partition/`, only if your first mount it using GUI, e.g:

```
/media/ravexina/af01656da-2149-9e293/
```

You can use:

```
ls -l /dev/disk/by-uuid/ | grep -i sd
```

to have a list of your partitions UUID's.

or:

```
sudo blkid /dev/sda1
```

for a specific partition.

Otherwise first you should find out which one of your partitions are actual "C:\" you can use `fdisk` for this purpose, e.g if your hard drive is `/dev/sda` then:

```
sudo fdisk -l /dev/sda
```

gives you a list of your partitions:

```
/dev/sda1  *       2048    999423    997354
/dev/sda2  *       1001470 9767710   97576960
```

Alternatively you can use `grep sd /proc/partitions` too.

then you can figure out which one of them is your "C:\" drive (Based on the partition size).

After that mount them somewhere, let's say `/dev/sda1` is your "C:\" drive:

```
sudo mount /dev/sda1 /mnt
```

now it will be available to you at `/mnt`

Comment: Excellent Answer. Thank you for the quick response.

Comment: You're welcome, Glad that I could help :)